# Cannot Load Routes in ./src/routes/index.js from ./app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

very new to nodejs here. I've tried to put routes in `app.js` without problem. However, after moving all the routes to a separate file under `PROJECT_DIR/src/routes/index.js`, and then I open the page in browser it says "Cannot GET `/wines`". Here's code in `app.js` and `src/routes/index.js`:

```
// app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

global.app = express();
require('./src/routes/index');
// also tried: require(path.join(__dirname, './src/routes/index'));

global.server = app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

```
// ./src/routes/index.js
// tried console.error(app); and it printed all the stuff about app in the server log
app.get('/wines', function(req, res) {
  res.send([{name:'w1'}, {name:'w2'}]);
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});
```

I'm sure I'm missing something. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should take a look, how [express-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator) build application structure

Comment: Whats the printout of path.join(__dirname, './src/routes/index') and does that path match?

Comment: does it work with '/'? (Do you get Hello World?)

Comment: var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router(); and than router.get...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Honestly, I am not sure why what you are doing does not work.

The file *can* be found because otherwise, Node would throw an error, and the fact that you can access `app` from the routes file means `app` is accessible.

I have a *suspicion* that this *may* be due to [*garbage collection*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) -- because you do not hold a reference to the module, it may be preemptively destroyed.

What's more, there is a construct in Express called a [*router*](http://expressjs.com/guide/routing.html) that *probably* exists for this exact purpose.

**Solution**

While I'm not sure about the problem I *am* sure about the solution -- use a router, like this:

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/wines', function(req, res) {
  res.send([{name:'w1'}, {name:'w2'}]);
});

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

And then in your `app.js` file, do this:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);
```

Another benefit of routers is that you do not have to pollute the global object anymore..

Comment: This works very well and more one thing learned-- Router. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use export in index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

and use it like this in app.js

```
var router = require('./src/routes/index');
```